# Link component interpolation error nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am getting this error in Next.js:

> Error: The provided 'href' (/subject/[subject]) value is missing query values (subject) to be interpolated properly. Read more: [https://err.sh/vercel/next.js/href-interpolation-failed`](https://err.sh/vercel/next.js/href-interpolation-failed%60).

I have a dynamic page set up as `/subject/[subject].tsx`. Now in my navigation I have:

```js
<Link href={'/subject/${subject}'} passHref><a>{subject}</a></Link>
```

It works fine when I access the page with different paths but when I am pressing on a button on the page it throws the error above which I imagine is because the component rerenders. If you go to the page in the error it says: `Note: this error will only show when the next/link component is clicked not when only rendered.`

I have tried to look for a solution and I tried doing:

```js
<Link href={{pathname: '/subject/[subject]', query: {subject: subject}}}></Link>
```

but nothing changed. I read the docs and it seems that the `as` prop is only an optional decorator that is not used anymore so I fail to see how that can help me.

Comment: Could it be a syntax issue? ``<Link href={`/subject/${subject}`} passHref><a>{subject}</a></Link>`` works for me (string with back-ticks rather than single quotes).

Comment: It's not I used single quotes because of the code formatting on this site, in the code I do use backticks.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same issue when trying to redirect user to locale. I did it in `useEffect`. After investigate I discovered that on first render `router.query` is empty, so it's missing required field `id`.  I fix it by using `router.isReady`

```js
export const useUserLanguageRoute = () => {
  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    const {
      locales = [],
      locale,
      asPath,
      defaultLocale,
      pathname,
      query,
      isReady // here it is
    } = router

    const browserLanguage = window.navigator.language.slice(0, 2)

    const shouldChangeLocale =
      isReady && // and here I use it
      locale !== browserLanguage
      && locale === defaultLocale
      && locales.includes(browserLanguage)

    if (shouldChangeLocale) {
      router.push(
        {
          pathname,
          query,
        },
        asPath,
        { locale: browserLanguage }
      )
    }
  }, [router])
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution could be redirect using the `router.push` function:

```
const myRedirectFunction = function () {

    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        router.push({
            pathname: router.pathname,
            query: {...router.query, myqueryparam: 'myvalue'},
        })
    }

}


return (
  <>
    <button onClick={() => {myRedirectFunction()}}> Continue </button>
  </>
```

)

It is important to include `...router.query` because there is where the [dynamic] current value is included, so we need to keep it.

Reference: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/master/errors/href-interpolation-failed.md

Comment: wow I had the same mysterious error (reference docs totally unhelpful). But the magic '...router.query` fix WFM as well. Still somewhat mystified as to why it's needed as I'm pushing to a different page which doesn't need (or want) the query-string params I have on the current page. Thanks though!

Comment: Seems a bug in nextjs AFAICT - tried latest version 10.0.9 and still has same issue

Answer (score 0):

You better do a `null || undefined` check in prior.

Comment: `<Link href={subject ? \`/subject/${subject}\` : "/"} key={subject} passHref>` I tried this and it doesn't seem to help me. Is that what you meant? I am getting the subject data client side.

Comment: I also have a `/book/[pid].tsx` page and when I got to it and press any buttons it shows the same error: `Error: The provided \`href\` (/book/[pid]) value is missing query values (pid) to be interpolated properly. Read more: https://err.sh/vercel/next.js/href-interpolation-failed`

Comment: in case of the dynamic routing: 
`
    <Link
      href={{
        pathname: '/book/[pid]',
        query: {pid: somevalue },
      }}
    >
      <a>Valid link</a>
    </Link>
`

Answer (score 0):

@Bentasy, Like you rightly pointed out, any re-render of the page is expecting you to pass in the dynamic route params again. The way I avoided page re-rendering with subsequent clicks on the page was to replace **Link** tag on the page with a **label** tag. I was using the Next Link tag to navigate between the tabs on this image which generated this same error. So I replaced the Link tags with label tags and the error was solved.
[image: The tabs on the page.]

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, this is how I solved it.

While pushing something to the router, we need to give the old values ​​in it.

In that:

```
const router = useRouter()

router.push({
   ...router,
   pathname: '/your-pathname'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try add this function, it work for me:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
return {
props: {},
};
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).