# NextJS Link href default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-link

I need a default href value for Next/Link, as we do in plain html like below

```
<a href='#' ></a>
```

I tried this to `Link` but it reloads the page, if I keep it empty it produces some error because its required attribute

```
<Link href='#'></Link>
```

Actually I am mapping a collection where some items does not have `href` so I need to put it blank and show some alert on click;

Answer (score 3):

### Conclusion

If you are using dynamic routing,

```html
<Link href=":"></Link>
```

will fix your issue.

### Explanation

Next.js only prefetches href if the link is local.

When the href does not starts with "/", "?", or "#", Next.js constructs URL and [checks if the URL is external or not](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/8b9ae8314e0a0747ba15f29f492c0b0bea5cde6d/packages/next/shared/lib/router/router.ts#L215).

```
const resolved = new URL(url, locationOrigin)
return resolved.origin === locationOrigin && hasBasePath(resolved.pathname)
```

When you pass empty string as href, Next.js thinks the link targets local URL, thus tries to prefetch the page, and fails if you have dynamic routing.

When you use `:` as href in `<Link>`, Next.js disables prefetch and fixes the issue. Although using `:` seems weird, it's actually recognized as a invalid "script" by the browser which should be ignored.

Though Next.js provides prefetch option, prefetch still occurs when you hover the link element even if you specify `prefetch={false}`, which causes the issue.

Answer (score -1):

If you use `<Link href=''></Link>` it won't produce any error, since it has its required attribute and its value is equal to `''`.

Comment: but it produces some error on click like 'The provided `href (/products/[product]) value is missing query values (product) to be interpolated properly.`

Comment: Yeah, I see now. It happens when we have nested routes. Can't you use `router.push` instead? This is similar to your problem: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65469874/link-component-interpolation-error-nextjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65469874/link-component-interpolation-error-nextjs)

Comment: That's not exactly what I want,  It should have some default value as we used to handle anchor tag in html

Comment: You can't do this. Whatever value that you set as default value will be considered as a **query**. The default value (similar to the anchor tag in HTML) works for cases that do not contain queries. So you should check the existence of `[product]` before using the `<Link>` tag and if it exists, pass the  `/products/[product]` to `href`.